# Using HttpContext.Items in Handlers in c#

Tags: c#, handlers

The problem is that I want to use "shared memory" in handlers to return the average of many integer values given but this code is not working, What should I do?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
    HttpResponse response=context.Response;
    HttpRequest request=context.Request;
    string x=request.UserHostAddress;
    if (int.Parse(request.QueryString["i2"])==0) {
        if (context.Items[x]==null) {
            al.Add(request.QueryString["i1"]);
            context.Items.Add(x, al);
        }
        else {
            al=(ArrayList)context.Items[x];
            al.Add(request.QueryString["i1"]);
        }
        response.Redirect("/Punto2.html");
    }
    else if(int.Parse(request.QueryString["i2"])==1) {
        if (context.Items[x]==null)
            response.Write("<h1>The ArrayList is null.</h1>");
        else {
            al=(ArrayList)context.Items[x];
            float a=0;
            for (int i=0; i<al.Count; i++) {
                a+=(int)al[i];
            } 
            a/=2;
            //response.Write("<h1>"+al.Count+"</h1>");
            response.Write("<h1>Average: "+a+"</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what level? Ie: connection/session/appdomain/farm?

Comment: Very unclear what you trying to do... Also you may want to read about per-request objects (like HttpContext.Items), per browser session object like `Session` and ways to transfer data between requests...